# Compile out code for release build in D

Tags: d

Is there any mechanism in D (D2) to force code to be compiled out during a release build?

In C, you might have something like

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
/*Something that will only run in a debug build*/
#endif
```

I know that D has

```
debug(mymodule) {
   //Do something
}
```

But this requires the user to pass -debug for each module to enable it.

I'm looking for a global mechanism that will always run the code in a normal build but compile it out when you pass the -release flag.  I know some built-ins have this ability (e.g. assert), but is there any way for user code to do it too?

Comment: I think that part of your problem is that `debug` and `-release` don't have anything to do with each other in D. `-release` implies that you're compiling a release version and it disables various checks (such as assertions). `-debug` enables the debug statements. As such, you could argue that there isn't really a "debug mode" in D. You have release mode and non-release mode with the ability to enable debug statements in either mode. I don't think that `-release` is supposed to really change the semantics of your code like `-debug` is, so that's likely why you can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm not looking to change the semantics for the release build.  I'm just looking for the best way to add extra checks, prints, etc in a non-release build that will be always on during development.  I see it as something to give a developer to track down issues more quickly.  The extra checks and warnings can give them a hint as to which modules they should enable -debug on.

Comment: I gave an answer, but somehow, I feel bad about it. I'd recommend just using -debug when devving and `debug{ //... }`. Better to make it easy to make mistakes when devving, than when releasing, imho.

Comment: Well, as the docs say for `-release`: "compile release version, which means not generating code for contracts and asserts. Array bounds checking is not done for system and trusted functions." It's not intended for enabling or disabling user code beyond what's in contracts and assertions. Even if all you intend to do is turn some of your own checks on or off, for better or for worse, that's not what `release` seems to be intended for. That's what `debug` is for, and if that's not fine-grained enough for you, then use `-version`. It is a bit confusing, but that appears to be how it is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a global notion of debug. Just write:

```
debug {
    ... code ...
}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be something simple like this.  The D Programming Language only mentioned the module-specific debug, so I hadn't realized there was a global one too.  Now I can use debug {...} for basic debugging and debug(mymodule) {...} to add more detailed debugging.

Comment: Exactly. Apologies for the omission. I have added an erratum on your behalf here: http://www.erdani.com/tdpl/errata/

Answer (score 3):

`dmd -release -version=dist module.d`

and

```
version(dist) {} else {
    int i = 9;
}
```

Best I can think of.

**[update]**

Personally, I think the above answer is "bad". The above solution would introduce overly complex logic into the release process, which I think should be straight forward and *predictable*. I'd recommend just using `-debug` and `debug{ //... }`. Even if you feel you might forget adding the debug-flag when you're compiling—you're just devving!—mistakes are cheap. Mistakes that make it into the release are worse.

Comment: It's not quite as ideal as I had hoped for, since you need to remember to specify the -version flag, but those details can probably be hidden from the end user inside the build system, so it'll do.

Answer (score 1):

If no better answer is found, a hackaround like this should work: `bool debugMode() { bool res; assert(!!(res = true)); return res; }`

Comment: That's assignment inside the assert.  In release mode, the assert and its contents are compiled out.  Thus, the assignment only takes place in non-release builds.

Comment: the OP is looking for a compile time solution and assert doesn't ever come out in CTFE.